# Why is $s=1$ in Dirichlet's Class Number Fomula when $L$-functions are only defined for $\Re(s)>1$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, l-functions

Given a quadratic number field $K$, let $w$ be the roots of unity, $d_K$ the discriminant, $h$ the class number and let $\varepsilon$ be the fundamental unit of $O_K$. We have that Dirichlet's Class Number formula is given by
\begin{equation}
    L(1,\left(\frac{d_K}{n}\right))=
    \begin{cases}
         \frac{2\pi h}{w\sqrt{|d_K|}} & \text{ if $d_K<0$}
         \\
         \frac{2h\log \varepsilon}{\sqrt{|d_K|}} & \text{ if $d_K>0$}.
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

I'm now wondering how this expression is well defined, as the definition of the $L$-function is:

Given a character $\chi$ (mod $q$) and for $\Re(s) >1$ we define:
\begin{equation}
    L(s, \chi)= \sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi (n)}{n^s}.
\end{equation}

Is it because we can make an analytic continuation of the $L$-function to $s=1$? And is it tricky to show that the $L$-function with $s=1$ is well defined? How could one show this? Or where should one look to read about this? Can't find much answer as I find most books just don't write explicitly why this holds.

Comment: since $\sum \chi(n)$ has bounded partial sums by periodicity, it is immediate that $L$ converges (conditionally but uniformly on compact sets) for $\Re s >0$ by partial summation (first for $s>0$ and then by the usual theory of Dirichlet series); for the class number formula, the Multiplicative Number Theory book by Davenport has a nice and fairly elementary step by step presentation in the first few chapters

Comment: For $\chi$ a non-trivial character.

Comment: And this is quadratic reciprocity that $(d_K/n)$ is a (non-trivial) Dirichlet character $\bmod 8 d_K$. There is also a more general way to find the meromorphic continuation of $\zeta_K(s)$ for any number field from which you know that $(s-1) \zeta_K(s)$ is analytic at $s=1$ (and its value is the general class number formula)

Comment: So if one can prove that $L(s,\left(\frac{d_K}{n}\right)$ is convergent for $\Re(s)>0$ (or even just $\Re(s) \geq 1$) then we have that $L(1,\left(\frac{d_K}{n}\right)$ is well defined? I'm I correct?

Comment: @slowpoke As long as the L function is attached with a principal character, it will be convergent in $\Re(s)>0$. This is a classical result in the theory of Dirichlet L functions.

Comment: @TravorLZH you mean *nonprincipal* (i.e., nontrivial) character.

Comment: @KCd thanks for the correction